# CSS files changes when I run ```npm run dev``

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, npm

I am working on a open source project, and there's this error that even when there are no images to show, the extension(The app is basically is a web browser extension which let's you search images) still shows the "Load More" button, so I thought I could remove this bug by adding the class ```removeButton`` to the button which applies the following setting

```css
removeButton{
display:none;
}
```

But when I run `npm run dev` to check the changes, the CSS files gets changed to the way it was before, how do I get around this or is there a better way to remove the LoadMore button ? At first I tried even deleting the button from DOM but that resulted in not showing the LoadMore button even when there were some more images to show.

This the output when I run ``npm run dev```

```
> ccsearch-browser-extension@1.0.0 dev /home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/ccsearch-browser-extension
> npm run clean && npm run compile-sass-popup:dev && npm run compile-sass-options:dev && npm run build-firefox && npm run build-chrome && npm run build-opera


> ccsearch-browser-extension@1.0.0 clean /home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/ccsearch-browser-extension
> rm -rf './dist'


> ccsearch-browser-extension@1.0.0 compile-sass-popup:dev /home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/ccsearch-browser-extension
> node-sass src/popup/sass/main.scss src/popup/popup.css

Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Wrote CSS to /home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/ccsearch-browser-extension/src/popup/popup.css

> ccsearch-browser-extension@1.0.0 compile-sass-options:dev /home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/ccsearch-browser-extension
> node-sass src/options/sass/main.scss src/options/options.css

Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Wrote CSS to /home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/ccsearch-browser-extension/src/options/options.css

> ccsearch-browser-extension@1.0.0 build-firefox /home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/ccsearch-browser-extension
> TARGET=firefox webpack --mode production

Building for firefox...
Hash: 8f02347ff3965262cd25
Version: webpack 4.35.2
Time: 1509ms
Built at: 01/27/2020 2:26:53 AM
                                               Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                                ./options/options.js   11.3 KiB       0  [emitted]  ./options/options
                                    ./popup/popup.js   49.8 KiB       1  [emitted]  ./popup/popup
                                     icons/cc128.png   1.98 KiB          [emitted]  
                                      icons/cc16.png  610 bytes          [emitted]  
                                      icons/cc24.png  829 bytes          [emitted]  
                                      icons/cc32.png   1.09 KiB          [emitted]  
                                      icons/cc48.png   1.59 KiB          [emitted]  
                                      icons/cc96.png   3.15 KiB          [emitted]  
                                       manifest.json  828 bytes          [emitted]  
                                 options/options.css   3.12 KiB          [emitted]  
                                options/options.html   13.4 KiB          [emitted]  
                         popup/img/cc-logo_white.png   9.77 KiB          [emitted]  
                           popup/img/ccheart_red.svg    1.9 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/license_logos/cc-by_icon.svg  980 bytes          [emitted]  
             popup/img/license_logos/cc-cc0_icon.svg   1.43 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/license_logos/cc-nc_icon.svg   1.33 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/license_logos/cc-nd_icon.svg  755 bytes          [emitted]  
             popup/img/license_logos/cc-pdm_icon.svg   1.04 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/license_logos/cc-sa_icon.svg   1.14 KiB          [emitted]  
                 popup/img/license_logos/cc_icon.svg   1.66 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/500px_logo.png   5.88 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/provider_logos/CAPL_logo.png   2.69 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/WoRMS_logo.png   5.95 KiB          [emitted]  
   popup/img/provider_logos/animaldiversity_logo.png   3.42 KiB          [emitted]  
           popup/img/provider_logos/behance_logo.svg   1.61 KiB          [emitted]  
    popup/img/provider_logos/brooklynmuseum_logo.png    5.2 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/cc-by_icon.svg  980 bytes          [emitted]  
            popup/img/provider_logos/cc-cc0_icon.svg   1.43 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/cc-nc_icon.svg   1.33 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/cc-nd_icon.svg  755 bytes          [emitted]  
  popup/img/provider_logos/cc-public-domain_icon.svg   1.04 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/cc-sa_icon.svg   1.14 KiB          [emitted]  
                popup/img/provider_logos/cc_icon.svg   1.66 KiB          [emitted]  
   popup/img/provider_logos/clevelandmuseum_logo.png   1.74 KiB          [emitted]  
        popup/img/provider_logos/deviantart_logo.png   4.36 KiB          [emitted]  
    popup/img/provider_logos/digitaltmuseum_logo.png  882 bytes          [emitted]  
               popup/img/provider_logos/eol_logo.png   1.79 KiB          [emitted]  
            popup/img/provider_logos/flickr_logo.png   4.52 KiB          [emitted]  
           popup/img/provider_logos/floraon_logo.png   8.65 KiB          [emitted]  
     popup/img/provider_logos/geographorguk_logo.png   2.98 KiB          [emitted]  
               popup/img/provider_logos/iha_logo.png   1.84 KiB          [emitted]  
      popup/img/provider_logos/mccordmuseum_logo.png   10.1 KiB          [emitted]  
               popup/img/provider_logos/met_logo.png    2.7 KiB          [emitted]  
   popup/img/provider_logos/museumsvictoria_logo.svg   1.67 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/provider_logos/nypl_logo.svg   11.3 KiB          [emitted]  
          popup/img/provider_logos/phylopic_logo.png   4.38 KiB          [emitted]  
          popup/img/provider_logos/rawpixel_logo.png   4.08 KiB          [emitted]  
       popup/img/provider_logos/rijksmuseum_logo.png   2.75 KiB          [emitted]  
     popup/img/provider_logos/sciencemuseum_logo.svg   1.79 KiB          [emitted]  
           popup/img/provider_logos/svgsilh_logo.png   2.81 KiB          [emitted]  
       popup/img/provider_logos/thingiverse_logo.png   1.22 KiB          [emitted]  
popup/img/provider_logos/thorvaldsensmuseum_logo.png   3.01 KiB          [emitted]  
         popup/img/provider_logos/wikimedia_logo.png   2.59 KiB          [emitted]  
                                     popup/popup.css   12.3 KiB          [emitted]  
                                    popup/popup.html     10 KiB          [emitted]  
                popup/vendors/css/comboTreestyle.css   1.37 KiB          [emitted]  
                   popup/vendors/js/clipboard.min.js   10.5 KiB          [emitted]  
                 popup/vendors/js/comboTreePlugin.js   7.87 KiB          [emitted]  
                popup/vendors/js/imagesloaded.min.js   5.46 KiB          [emitted]  
                      popup/vendors/js/jquery.min.js   86.1 KiB          [emitted]  
Entrypoint ./popup/popup = ./popup/popup.js
Entrypoint ./options/options = ./options/options.js
 [0] ./utils.js 2.93 KiB {0} {1} [built]
 [1] ./popup/helper.js 3.57 KiB {0} {1} [built]
[10] ./popup/popup.js + 6 modules 43.4 KiB {1} [built]
     | ./popup/popup.js 9.72 KiB [built]
     | ./popup/base.js 2.75 KiB [built]
     | ./popup/spinner.js 819 bytes [built]
     | ./popup/infoPopupModule.js 8.67 KiB [built]
     | ./popup/searchModule.js 9.12 KiB [built]
     | ./popup/filterModule.js 1.75 KiB [built]
     | ./popup/bookmarkModule.js 10.6 KiB [built]
[11] ./options/options.js + 2 modules 6.99 KiB {0} [built]
     | ./options/options.js 3.58 KiB [built]
     | ./options/base.js 722 bytes [built]
     | ./options/helper.js 2.7 KiB [built]
    + 8 hidden modules

> ccsearch-browser-extension@1.0.0 build-chrome /home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/ccsearch-browser-extension
> TARGET=chrome webpack --mode production

Building for chrome...
Hash: 8f02347ff3965262cd25
Version: webpack 4.35.2
Time: 438ms
Built at: 01/27/2020 2:26:54 AM
                                               Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                                ./options/options.js   11.3 KiB       0  [emitted]  ./options/options
                                    ./popup/popup.js   49.8 KiB       1  [emitted]  ./popup/popup
                                     icons/cc128.png   1.98 KiB          [emitted]  
                                      icons/cc16.png  610 bytes          [emitted]  
                                      icons/cc24.png  829 bytes          [emitted]  
                                      icons/cc32.png   1.09 KiB          [emitted]  
                                      icons/cc48.png   1.59 KiB          [emitted]  
                                      icons/cc96.png   3.15 KiB          [emitted]  
                                       manifest.json  805 bytes          [emitted]  
                                 options/options.css   3.12 KiB          [emitted]  
                                options/options.html   13.4 KiB          [emitted]  
                         popup/img/cc-logo_white.png   9.77 KiB          [emitted]  
                           popup/img/ccheart_red.svg    1.9 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/license_logos/cc-by_icon.svg  980 bytes          [emitted]  
             popup/img/license_logos/cc-cc0_icon.svg   1.43 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/license_logos/cc-nc_icon.svg   1.33 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/license_logos/cc-nd_icon.svg  755 bytes          [emitted]  
             popup/img/license_logos/cc-pdm_icon.svg   1.04 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/license_logos/cc-sa_icon.svg   1.14 KiB          [emitted]  
                 popup/img/license_logos/cc_icon.svg   1.66 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/500px_logo.png   5.88 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/provider_logos/CAPL_logo.png   2.69 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/WoRMS_logo.png   5.95 KiB          [emitted]  
   popup/img/provider_logos/animaldiversity_logo.png   3.42 KiB          [emitted]  
           popup/img/provider_logos/behance_logo.svg   1.61 KiB          [emitted]  
    popup/img/provider_logos/brooklynmuseum_logo.png    5.2 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/cc-by_icon.svg  980 bytes          [emitted]  
            popup/img/provider_logos/cc-cc0_icon.svg   1.43 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/cc-nc_icon.svg   1.33 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/cc-nd_icon.svg  755 bytes          [emitted]  
  popup/img/provider_logos/cc-public-domain_icon.svg   1.04 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/cc-sa_icon.svg   1.14 KiB          [emitted]  
                popup/img/provider_logos/cc_icon.svg   1.66 KiB          [emitted]  
   popup/img/provider_logos/clevelandmuseum_logo.png   1.74 KiB          [emitted]  
        popup/img/provider_logos/deviantart_logo.png   4.36 KiB          [emitted]  
    popup/img/provider_logos/digitaltmuseum_logo.png  882 bytes          [emitted]  
               popup/img/provider_logos/eol_logo.png   1.79 KiB          [emitted]  
            popup/img/provider_logos/flickr_logo.png   4.52 KiB          [emitted]  
           popup/img/provider_logos/floraon_logo.png   8.65 KiB          [emitted]  
     popup/img/provider_logos/geographorguk_logo.png   2.98 KiB          [emitted]  
               popup/img/provider_logos/iha_logo.png   1.84 KiB          [emitted]  
      popup/img/provider_logos/mccordmuseum_logo.png   10.1 KiB          [emitted]  
               popup/img/provider_logos/met_logo.png    2.7 KiB          [emitted]  
   popup/img/provider_logos/museumsvictoria_logo.svg   1.67 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/provider_logos/nypl_logo.svg   11.3 KiB          [emitted]  
          popup/img/provider_logos/phylopic_logo.png   4.38 KiB          [emitted]  
          popup/img/provider_logos/rawpixel_logo.png   4.08 KiB          [emitted]  
       popup/img/provider_logos/rijksmuseum_logo.png   2.75 KiB          [emitted]  
     popup/img/provider_logos/sciencemuseum_logo.svg   1.79 KiB          [emitted]  
           popup/img/provider_logos/svgsilh_logo.png   2.81 KiB          [emitted]  
       popup/img/provider_logos/thingiverse_logo.png   1.22 KiB          [emitted]  
popup/img/provider_logos/thorvaldsensmuseum_logo.png   3.01 KiB          [emitted]  
         popup/img/provider_logos/wikimedia_logo.png   2.59 KiB          [emitted]  
                                     popup/popup.css   12.3 KiB          [emitted]  
                                    popup/popup.html     10 KiB          [emitted]  
                popup/vendors/css/comboTreestyle.css   1.37 KiB          [emitted]  
                   popup/vendors/js/clipboard.min.js   10.5 KiB          [emitted]  
                 popup/vendors/js/comboTreePlugin.js   7.87 KiB          [emitted]  
                popup/vendors/js/imagesloaded.min.js   5.46 KiB          [emitted]  
                      popup/vendors/js/jquery.min.js   86.1 KiB          [emitted]  
Entrypoint ./popup/popup = ./popup/popup.js
Entrypoint ./options/options = ./options/options.js
 [0] ./utils.js 2.93 KiB {0} {1} [built]
 [1] ./popup/helper.js 3.57 KiB {0} {1} [built]
[10] ./popup/popup.js + 6 modules 43.4 KiB {1} [built]
     | ./popup/popup.js 9.72 KiB [built]
     | ./popup/base.js 2.75 KiB [built]
     | ./popup/spinner.js 819 bytes [built]
     | ./popup/infoPopupModule.js 8.67 KiB [built]
     | ./popup/searchModule.js 9.12 KiB [built]
     | ./popup/filterModule.js 1.75 KiB [built]
     | ./popup/bookmarkModule.js 10.6 KiB [built]
[11] ./options/options.js + 2 modules 6.99 KiB {0} [built]
     | ./options/options.js 3.58 KiB [built]
     | ./options/base.js 722 bytes [built]
     | ./options/helper.js 2.7 KiB [built]
    + 8 hidden modules

> ccsearch-browser-extension@1.0.0 build-opera /home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/ccsearch-browser-extension
> TARGET=opera webpack --mode production

Building for opera...
Hash: 8f02347ff3965262cd25
Version: webpack 4.35.2
Time: 387ms
Built at: 01/27/2020 2:26:55 AM
                                               Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                                ./options/options.js   11.3 KiB       0  [emitted]  ./options/options
                                    ./popup/popup.js   49.8 KiB       1  [emitted]  ./popup/popup
                                     icons/cc128.png   1.98 KiB          [emitted]  
                                      icons/cc16.png  610 bytes          [emitted]  
                                      icons/cc24.png  829 bytes          [emitted]  
                                      icons/cc32.png   1.09 KiB          [emitted]  
                                      icons/cc48.png   1.59 KiB          [emitted]  
                                      icons/cc96.png   3.15 KiB          [emitted]  
                                       manifest.json  805 bytes          [emitted]  
                                 options/options.css   3.12 KiB          [emitted]  
                                options/options.html   13.4 KiB          [emitted]  
                         popup/img/cc-logo_white.png   9.77 KiB          [emitted]  
                           popup/img/ccheart_red.svg    1.9 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/license_logos/cc-by_icon.svg  980 bytes          [emitted]  
             popup/img/license_logos/cc-cc0_icon.svg   1.43 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/license_logos/cc-nc_icon.svg   1.33 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/license_logos/cc-nd_icon.svg  755 bytes          [emitted]  
             popup/img/license_logos/cc-pdm_icon.svg   1.04 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/license_logos/cc-sa_icon.svg   1.14 KiB          [emitted]  
                 popup/img/license_logos/cc_icon.svg   1.66 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/500px_logo.png   5.88 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/provider_logos/CAPL_logo.png   2.69 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/WoRMS_logo.png   5.95 KiB          [emitted]  
   popup/img/provider_logos/animaldiversity_logo.png   3.42 KiB          [emitted]  
           popup/img/provider_logos/behance_logo.svg   1.61 KiB          [emitted]  
    popup/img/provider_logos/brooklynmuseum_logo.png    5.2 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/cc-by_icon.svg  980 bytes          [emitted]  
            popup/img/provider_logos/cc-cc0_icon.svg   1.43 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/cc-nc_icon.svg   1.33 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/cc-nd_icon.svg  755 bytes          [emitted]  
  popup/img/provider_logos/cc-public-domain_icon.svg   1.04 KiB          [emitted]  
             popup/img/provider_logos/cc-sa_icon.svg   1.14 KiB          [emitted]  
                popup/img/provider_logos/cc_icon.svg   1.66 KiB          [emitted]  
   popup/img/provider_logos/clevelandmuseum_logo.png   1.74 KiB          [emitted]  
        popup/img/provider_logos/deviantart_logo.png   4.36 KiB          [emitted]  
    popup/img/provider_logos/digitaltmuseum_logo.png  882 bytes          [emitted]  
               popup/img/provider_logos/eol_logo.png   1.79 KiB          [emitted]  
            popup/img/provider_logos/flickr_logo.png   4.52 KiB          [emitted]  
           popup/img/provider_logos/floraon_logo.png   8.65 KiB          [emitted]  
     popup/img/provider_logos/geographorguk_logo.png   2.98 KiB          [emitted]  
               popup/img/provider_logos/iha_logo.png   1.84 KiB          [emitted]  
      popup/img/provider_logos/mccordmuseum_logo.png   10.1 KiB          [emitted]  
               popup/img/provider_logos/met_logo.png    2.7 KiB          [emitted]  
   popup/img/provider_logos/museumsvictoria_logo.svg   1.67 KiB          [emitted]  
              popup/img/provider_logos/nypl_logo.svg   11.3 KiB          [emitted]  
          popup/img/provider_logos/phylopic_logo.png   4.38 KiB          [emitted]  
          popup/img/provider_logos/rawpixel_logo.png   4.08 KiB          [emitted]  
       popup/img/provider_logos/rijksmuseum_logo.png   2.75 KiB          [emitted]  
     popup/img/provider_logos/sciencemuseum_logo.svg   1.79 KiB          [emitted]  
           popup/img/provider_logos/svgsilh_logo.png   2.81 KiB          [emitted]  
       popup/img/provider_logos/thingiverse_logo.png   1.22 KiB          [emitted]  
popup/img/provider_logos/thorvaldsensmuseum_logo.png   3.01 KiB          [emitted]  
         popup/img/provider_logos/wikimedia_logo.png   2.59 KiB          [emitted]  
                                     popup/popup.css   12.3 KiB          [emitted]  
                                    popup/popup.html     10 KiB          [emitted]  
                popup/vendors/css/comboTreestyle.css   1.37 KiB          [emitted]  
                   popup/vendors/js/clipboard.min.js   10.5 KiB          [emitted]  
                 popup/vendors/js/comboTreePlugin.js   7.87 KiB          [emitted]  
                popup/vendors/js/imagesloaded.min.js   5.46 KiB          [emitted]  
                      popup/vendors/js/jquery.min.js   86.1 KiB          [emitted]  
Entrypoint ./popup/popup = ./popup/popup.js
Entrypoint ./options/options = ./options/options.js
 [0] ./utils.js 2.93 KiB {0} {1} [built]
 [1] ./popup/helper.js 3.57 KiB {0} {1} [built]
[10] ./popup/popup.js + 6 modules 43.4 KiB {1} [built]
     | ./popup/popup.js 9.72 KiB [built]
     | ./popup/base.js 2.75 KiB [built]
     | ./popup/spinner.js 819 bytes [built]
     | ./popup/infoPopupModule.js 8.67 KiB [built]
     | ./popup/searchModule.js 9.12 KiB [built]
     | ./popup/filterModule.js 1.75 KiB [built]
     | ./popup/bookmarkModule.js 10.6 KiB [built]
[11] ./options/options.js + 2 modules 6.99 KiB {0} [built]
     | ./options/options.js 3.58 KiB [built]
     | ./options/base.js 722 bytes [built]
     | ./options/helper.js 2.7 KiB [built]
    + 8 hidden modules
```

Contents of `package.json` file

```js
{
  "name": "ccsearch-browser-extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "CC Search Browser Extension.",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint './src/**/*.js'",
    "compile-sass-popup:dev": "node-sass src/popup/sass/main.scss src/popup/popup.css",
    "compile-sass-options:dev": "node-sass src/options/sass/main.scss src/options/options.css",
    "compile-sass-popup:prod": "node-sass src/popup/sass/main.scss src/popup/popup.css --output-style compressed",
    "compile-sass-options:prod": "node-sass src/options/sass/main.scss src/options/options.css --output-style compressed",
    "compile-sass-popup:watch": "node-sass src/popup/sass/main.scss src/popup/popup.css --watch ",
    "compile-sass-options:watch": "node-sass src/options/sass/main.scss src/options/options.css --watch",
    "clean": "rm -rf './dist'",
    "build-chrome": "TARGET=chrome webpack --mode production",
    "build-firefox": "TARGET=firefox webpack --mode production",
    "build-opera": "TARGET=opera webpack --mode production",
    "package-source-code": "zip -r source-code.zip src tests package.json package-lock.json babel.config.js webpack.config.js LICENSE README.firefox.md",
    "package-chrome": "npm run dev && (cd dist/chrome/ && zip -r ../chrome.zip .)",
    "package-firefox": "npm run dev && (cd dist/firefox/ && zip -r ../firefox.zip .) && npm run package-source-code",
    "dev": "npm run clean && npm run compile-sass-popup:dev && npm run compile-sass-options:dev && npm run build-firefox && npm run build-chrome && npm run build-opera",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run compile-sass-popup:prod && npm run compile-sass-options:prod && npm run build-firefox && npm run build-chrome && npm run build-opera",
    "webpack-watch:firefox": "TARGET=chrome webpack --watch",
    "webpack-watch:chrome": "TARGET=chrome webpack --watch",
    "webpack-watch:opera": "TARGET=opera webpack --watch",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/creativecommons/ccsearch-browser-extension.git"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/creativecommons/ccsearch-browser-extension/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/creativecommons/ccsearch-browser-extension#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.17",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.3",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack": "^4.35.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
    "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.removeButton` ?

Comment: What does `npm run dev` exactly do? Paste the contents of the `commands` object from the package.json file.

Comment: Yeah,sorry that was just a typing error in question.The error persists

Comment: Contents of package.json file

Comment: Which file are you trying to edit? Please specify the path.

Comment: I am trying to edit popup.js file. Here's the link to the repo [link](https://github.com/creativecommons/ccsearch-browser-extension)

Comment: I meant the CSS file you're trying to edit.

Comment: popup.css is the file I am trying to edit. Path is `src/popup`

Comment: Yes, as I've said in my answer that's a file that is compiled from SASS. You need to edit the .scss files instead. I've linked the location to the SASS files in my answer below.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is probably because you're `npm run dev` is compiling a SASS file and you're editing the compiled/another CSS file. Make sure you're editing the SASS file.

In your provided repo, the SASS files are [here](https://github.com/creativecommons/ccsearch-browser-extension/tree/master/src/popup/sass) - I expect you're editing the compiled CSS files so make sure you're editing these .scss ones instead.

Comment: Thanks, now I am able to fix the error and by changing the scss files. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem! Have a great day